# Auto hide notification bar when show

Tags: java, android

I have the notification bar hidden from the application, but when I swipe down, the notification bar shows and doesn't hide. Does anyone know how I can autohide the notification bar when it is swiped?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to simply remove the notification/status bar entirely from your app?

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml should do just that.

Comment: This doesn't allow the user to access the notification bar but it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [`setSystemUiVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29)?

In that case, you might want to include the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` (or probably `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`) flags.

See [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html). (API 19+)

Comment: It requires API 19+ where my minimum API is 8.

Comment: @user2468723 I would suggest doing it conditionally then. AFAIK "permanently invisible" status bar isn't possible before API 19. See https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/index.html